# How to get the drawable image path in android?

Tags: java, android, image, android-drawable

Hello I want to get the drawable image path in android and then I want to create a file ? can anybody help me there ?

Comment: `path` you mean the path to the file?

Comment: yes I want to assign the path of drawable image to a file and make a file ?

Comment: you can't get a path of a drawable, as not all drawables were created from files, and they don't store the path anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you want how to save image to sdcard from drawable resource. right?

At first get bitmap from your drawable resource and then save bitmap as image in your required location

```
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource( getResources(), R.drawable.my_image);
```

The path to SD Card can be retrieved using:

```
String extStorageDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
```

Then save to sdcard

```
File file = new File(extStorageDirectory, "myimagefile.png");
FileOutputStream outStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, outStream);
outStream.flush();
outStream.close();
```

Don't forget to add android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission in your manifest file.

Comment: Thanks Alot I have done this with bitmap as you said above. I got bitmap from drawable and then I save bitmap in a local directoty and then I got it's path.
it's worked in my case.